Guidelines of retroactive hefkering of items
I was speaking with a senior rabbi (40 years + of Orthodox rabbi-ing) and he revealed to me that bais din sometimes resolve aguna issues by retroactively invalidating the initial marriage, by declaring the item used to effect the marriage to have been ownerless when the man gave it to the bride. The rabbi didn't elaborate much and behaved as if he had already said too much.
What are the guidelines for a bais din to use this power? I had never heard of it before.

I believe this is the rule known as אפקעינהו, and it is discussed in yevamos as well as elsewhere (especially gittin). It's a machlokes rishonim AFAIK why it works, and when, but the rabbi you were talking to probably was referencing this. It's based on "hefker beis din hefker"

Do we have any rules on this from more modern times? Are there RCA rules?

I'm not sure, but a quick look at those gemaras (which can be found on the אפקעינהו Hebrew Wikipedia page) should point you to the relevant rambam and shulchan aruch simanim
